# Nested Model returning null in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, null

I know this question has been asked before however i am struggling to find a suitable solution. I have a `foreach loop` which compares values from 2 models and decides which parent element each belong to as you can see in my View (Table has expand/close capability) so i want each Group to appear under the section they have been allocated to, however when I call `item.Group.GroupSectionID` it returns null every time, but when debugging the controller is populating the `GroupDetail` model and the `SectionDetail` model is being populated but the `public GroupDetail Group { get; set; }` is returning null:

**View (SectionTable)**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
    <!-- Render the details of each employee. -->
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Name)</td>
    </tr>

    if (item.Group.GroupSectionID != 0 && item.SectionID == item.Group.GroupSectionID)
    {
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><p>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Group.GroupName)</p></td>
    </tr>
    }
    }

    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Controllers**

```
public ActionResult GroupTable()
{
    Manager manager = new Manager();
    var data1 = manager.GetAllGroups();
    var groupDetails = from u in data1
    select new GroupDetail
    {
        GroupID = u.Id,
                GroupDescription = u.Description,
                GroupName = u.Name,
                GroupSectionID = u.SectionId,
                SectionName = u.SectionName
    };
    return View(groupDetails.ToList());
}

public ActionResult SectionTable()
{
    Manager manager = new Manager();
    var data3 = manager.GetAllSections();
    var sectionDetails = from u in data3
    select new SectionDetail
    {
        SectionID = u.Id,
                Name = u.Name,
                Description = u.Description
    };
    return View(sectionDetails.ToList());
}
```

**Models**

```
public class SectionDetail
{
    public int SectionID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public GroupDetail Group { get; set; }

}

public class GroupDetail
{
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    public string GroupDescription { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public int GroupSectionID { get; set; }
    public string SectionName { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in advance and if you want any further info please ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't assign Group property here:

```
var sectionDetails = from u in data3
                     select new SectionDetail
                               {
                                   SectionID = u.Id,
                                   Name = u.Name,
                                   Description = u.Description,
                                   Group = u.Group
                               };
```

Comment: While this correctly initializes and populates you `Group` property, it suggests you view code is a bit pointless since `if (item.Group.GroupSectionID != 0 && item.SectionID == item.Group.GroupSectionID)` should always evaluate to `true` so its unnecessary extra overhead. Just remove the surrouding `if` block - you just need the `@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Group.GroupName)`

Comment: As always @StephenMuecke you are spot on, I already did this :), thanks